# Por que o estado inicial de um <input> com required é inválido?

Tags: html, input

Quando eu coloco uma ou mais restrições em um `<input>`, inicialmente seu estado aparece como `invalid`. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```css
input {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
}

input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
    border-color:green;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Somente Digitos" min="1"/>
```

Note que, assim que carregado o código a borda do `<input>` aparece em cor vermelha por ser um campo requerido (definido no CSS para exibi-la desta forma quando o valor no `input` estiver incorreto).

Minha dúvida é:
Como faço para o `input` se mostrar neutro assim que carregada a página? Isto é, sem exibir o verde/vermelho definido no CSS. (ou melhor: Como faço para ele não iniciar no estado `:invalid`? ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tem ao mesmo tempo um campo `required` e um campo vazio, ele de fato é um campo inválido - afinal, um campo requerido, para ser válido precisa ter dados :)

O que dá para fazer neste caso, para melhorar a experiência inicial do usuário, é "atrasar" o CSS para aparecer somente depois que haja interação com o form.

Nesta intenção, seguem duas soluções intermediárias. Uma se baseia no `autofocus`, e é puro CSS. A outra tem alguma similaridade com a resposta do @Sergio, mas com vistas a casos em que haja o botão de envio (ou outro procedimento equivalente).

### Para um campo só: CSS

Se você tem um campo único, dá pra resolver sem JS:

- Defina o campo como `autofocus`;
- estilize com CSS para que enquanto o campo tenha foco, fique "neutro".

```css
input             { border: 2px solid #ccc; padding: 8px; }
input:invalid     { border-color: red; }
input:valid,
input:focus:valid { border-color:green; }
input:focus       { border-color: #ccc; !important; }
```

```html
<input required type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Somente Digitos" min="1" autofocus />
```

### Para vários campos: JS

A função JS a seguir faz com que, além do campo responder visualmente aos requisitos na perda do foco, numa eventual tentativa de envio faça com que os campos todos recebam o CSS indicando seu status.

Desta forma, o *feedback* acontece no *form* todo mesmo sem determinado campo ter sido visitado.

```js
var hi = document.querySelectorAll('input.off');
for (var i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) hi[i].onblur = function(){ this.classList.add('hl'); }
function highlightAll() { for (var i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) hi[i].classList.add('hl'); }
```

```css
input            { border: 2px solid #ccc; padding: 8px; }
input.hl:invalid { border-color: red; }
input.hl:valid   { border-color:green; }
```

```html
<input class="off" type="text" required pattern="\d*" placeholder="Somente Digitos" min="1" /><br>
<input class="off" type="text" required placeholder="Qualquer coisa" /><br>
<input class="off" type="text" placeholder="Campo não obrigatório" /><br>
<button onClick="highlightAll()">enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

O que gera esse comportamento é a propriedade `required`. Ou seja ter um `input` com `required` e sem `value` definido (ou inserido) faz com que o input *não valide*. Ou seja o browser sabe que este campo é obrigatório e que está vazio, assim o seu estado é *inválido`* e o CSS reflete isso.

Dando `value="0"` ou tirando o `required` (como no exemplo em baixo) funciona como esperado.

```css
input {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
}

input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
    border-color:green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Somente Digitos"  min="1"/>
```

Para contornar este problema tem de usar JavaScript. Por exemplo:

```js
var required = document.querySelector('input[required]');
required.onblur = function(){ this.classList.add('visitado'); };
```

```css
input {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
}

input.visitado:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
    border-color:green;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Somente Digitos" min="1"/>
```

Comment: Acontece que se o campo tiver um valor inicial o `placeholder` não irá aparecer. Tem como iniciar o input com um estado "neutro"? Nem `valid`, nem `invalid`?

Comment: @rnxn como escrevi na resposta tem de dar algum value, zero por exemplo, ou usar JavaScript. Não há forma de "desligar" em CSS.